# Customize ListView control in Universal Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I have a listview control in my application. I now wish to change the image on selection change of list view. Below is my listview control.  I have also created an itemcontainerstyle for styling my listview on selection change.

```
<ListView x:Name="itemListView" Margin="5" Grid.Row="2" SelectionChanged="itemListView_SelectionChanged" DoubleTapped="itemListView_DoubleTapped"
                              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Width="Auto" Margin="5">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Image Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets/chart52.png" Width="50" 
                                       Height="50"/>

                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding dash_name}" MaxHeight="60" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                           TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

This is my style in App.xaml file

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>

                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Transparent"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="White"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#5F151515"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FFEE840B"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <Border x:Name="myback" Background="Transparent">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

How can i change my image in this style? Any ideas on how to do it.

Thanks,
Samarth

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Model and have a BitmapImage Binded to you ListItem image. 
That way you can manage the ListItems easily.
Also add INotifyPropertyChanged.

Then on Selection Change you can call the Item Class of the selected items for example like this

```
 List<YourItemClass> selectedItems = listview.SelectedItems.Cast<YourItemClass>().ToList();
```

or if its tapped like this

```
YourItemClass selectedItem = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as YourItemClass;
```

and do

```
//your new image
selectedItem.Image = new BitmapImage();
```

Links:

[Data binding overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt269383.aspx)

[INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged)